# noinitrd is ignored, always runs initrd copy of /init

Tags: linux, root, initrd

I use an initrd currently on an imx8 processor that uses buildroot for a base filesystem. (kernel is 5.10.52)

For debugging purposes, I want to bypass the initrd and load the filesystem I copied to a real device partition (`/dev/mmcblk2p2`) -- so I pass:

```
noinitrd root=/dev/mmcblk2p2 init=/linuxrc
```

to the kernel command line.

It gets completely ignored and boots /linuxrc that is in the initrd.

console shows:
Run /init as init process

no matter what... and /proc/cmdline shows the parameters I pass in...

Is noinitrd ignored? Are there any magic paramters that allow my system to boot off a physical partition with noinitrd specified?

Comment: Why not just remove the `initrd` line?

Comment: there is no initrd in the command line...

Comment: There should be an initrd / initramfs line somewhere. Like for Raspberry Pi, it is in /boot/config.txt (while the kernel command line is in /boot/cmdline.txt). Although to be frank, I don't know for sure if it's impossible for a kernel to have a static/fallback initrd/initramfs path in it.

Comment: the initrd is specified in the kernel config. My point is the override of "noinitrd" is being ignored. Is it supposed to work always if specified?